# Modifying TNT Explosions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Would it be possible to modify the explosion strength of TNT (via MCEdit, NBTEdit, etc.) to a point that it would be able to blow up Obsidian or possibly even Bedrock?

Comment: I don't think you can do this through any of the programs you suggested, however I do believe you can mod it yourself. Seach "how to mod minecraft" and when you learn the basics, you can learn to mod certain block elements. This isn't an answer, as I am unsure.

Comment: It is possible to change fuse duration and explosion radius with MCEdit, but not explosion strength.

Comment: @BlaXpirit Thanks for clearing that up. I wasn't sure what properties of TNT you could edit in MCEdit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MCEdit is a world editor. Same for NBTEdit. To do what you are asking for, you should use a mod (or in the worse case scenario write one yourself) to modify that behavior.

Comment: Yep, this. The explosion strength of TNT is hardcoded into Minecraft. You could only change it with a mod, and it would change all TNT blocks, not just the ones you wanted.

Comment: If you do mod it to blow up Obsidian, make sure you stand well clear of the blast radius...

Comment: Make it only blow nearby obsidian and regular blocks which are further away.

Answer (score 3):

According to [minecraftwiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion#Blast_resistance), obsidian has a blast resistance of 6,000, bedrock has 18,000,000. These blocks are not indestructible, but nothing in vanilla minecraft can create an explosion that is destructive enough. (Compare: blast resistance of a diamond block is 30.) The explosion required to break bedrock would have an explosion radius of 30,000,000 blocks.

None of the tools you listed can modify minecraft this way. There are however several mods that can, for example the [more explosives mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/877105-152-smp-more-explosives-mod-over-1500000-downloads/).

Answer (score 2):

you do can explode obsidian and bedrock, but not with a tnt, you will need a command to summon a fireball:

```
     /summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower:1}
```

than you can change the explosion power to wathever you want.
(a tnt has an explosion power of 4)

more information, check out this video:

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 1.8.3 and they released an update at some time that allows this command to change explosion power:

```
/gamerule explosion power 1000000
```

or another desired number for explosion power.
I've tested this many times and it works great. Cheats must be on.